# Improve sql query performance by using ordering?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a SQLServer database with tables containing temperature measurements.

The tables have columns for MeasurementId(prim key), SensorId, Timestamp and Value.

We now have have enough measurements that our queries are starting to get a little bit slow and I'm trying to improve this.

The Timestamp values are not necessarily in order, but for each SensorId they are ordered. 
My question is: Is there anyway I can use this knowlegde to improve the performance of a query like `SELECT * FROM MeasurmentTable WHERE SensorId=xx AND Timestamp>yy` ?

I.e, can i hint to SQL Server that once you've narrowed your results to a unique SensorId, the rows are guaranteed to be ordered by timestamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your query, you simply want a composite index:

```
create index idx_measurementtable_sensorid_timestamp
    on MeasurementTable(SensorId, Timestamp);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had that in mind but I couldn't quite wrap my head around how it works. Will look into it some more.